# Django 1.10: CSRF Token issue in Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I am creating my AJAX request like this:

```
data.push({'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrf, 'answers': answers})

        $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/en/list/add/",
                data: JSON.stringify(data),
                dataType: 'json'
            }).done(function (data) {
            console.log(data)
        });
```

But I am still getting error **CSRF token missing or incorrect.**

Comment: Did you do that https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/csrf/#ajax ?

Answer (score 0):

Django will only parse the request body if it is encoded as form data (either as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or as `multipart/form-data`). Since your data is a JSON string, the body is not parsed, and Django can't find the csrf token in `request.POST`.

So if you're using JSON to encode the request body, you need to use the `X-CsrfToken` header instead. There are some examples in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/csrf/#ajax).